# Return Observable to replace values for multiple parameter?

Tags: angular, observable

I am returning an Observable for a function with 3(one, two, three) parameters to get replace with the config URL. For Ex. http://www.example.com/status?a={0}&b={1}&c={2}.

My Code:

```
getLink(one string, two: string, three): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.of([this.externalLinks['url'].replace('\{0\}', one),
    this.externalLinks['url'].replace('\{1\}', two),
    this.externalLinks['url'].replace('\{2\}', three)]);
}
```

I am not able to return multiple values and replace the parameters. I would like to know, how to return all the three values and replace config URL.
I would appreciate for any clue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple (or I got it wrong) :

```js
getLink(one string, two: string, three): Observable<{
  url: string,
  replacedUrl: string,
  value1: string,
  value2: string,
  value3: string
}> {
  return Observable.of({
    url: this.externalLinks['url'],
    replacedUrl: this.externalLinks['url']
      .replace(`{0}`, one)
      .replace(`{1}`, two)
      .replace(`{2}`, three),
    value1: one,
    value2: two,
    value3: three,
  });
}
```

your Answer will be :

```js
this.myService.getLink('one', 'two', 'three').subscribe(obj => {
  console.log(obj.url); // base URL
  console.log(obj.replacedUrl); // your URL completed
  console.log(obj.value1); // 'one'
  console.log(obj.value2); // 'two'
  console.log(obj.value3); // 'three'
});
```